# How do I use jQuery to pull a name attribute from a SPAN element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, greasemonkey

I have an HTML file that I'm scraping with a greasemonkey script in which I'm using jQuery.

The HTML page is very long, but I have a number of `<span>` elements throughout the page.

Let's assume that the elements look like this:

```
<span id="spnMX45" name="spnMX45" >16</span>
<span id="spnMX46" name="spnMX46" >10</span>
<span id="spnMX47" name="spnMX47" >11</span>
<span id="spnMX48" name="spnMX48" >5</span>
```

There are two values that I need from each of these elements: I need the number that comes after the "spnMX" and the text of the span.

I'm going to populate an array with these values and send them off for processing. The majority of this I can do, but grabbing the `name` or `id` attributes have been a problem.

Here's what I have at the moment:

```
// Grab Max Points for assessments
var maxPointsArray = $("span[id^=spnMX]").map(
    function(data){
    arr = [this.Attr('name')];
    return arr;
    }
);

console.log(maxPointsArray.length);  // yields:  9 <--actual number of span elements in test html
console.log(maxPointsArray);  // yields:  9 undefined objects
```

I've tried:

```
arr = [this.name];
arr = this.name;
arr = [this.attr('name')];
arr = this.Attr('name');
```

I just can't seem to get it.  Are span attributes unable to be grabbed?  I doubt it, but I can't figure this one out.  I've done this exact thing with several different input-type elements successfully.  I can't grab the `text()` of this object successfully, but I can't seem to get that dang name, or id even, attribute.

Comment: $(this).attr('name');

Comment: You can't have a name attribute on a span element, it isn't allowed in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:

- Javascript (and jQuery) is case-sensitive.  `.attr` is valid; `.Attr` is not.
- `this` inside a [`.map()`<sup>Doc</sup>](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=map) loop is not a jQuery object. So, in order to use jQuery functions like `.attr()`  you would need `$(this).attr()`.
- jQuery `.map()` is quite powerful at mapping arrays, but it returns a jQuery object.  Use `.get()` for the final result.
- Since your jQuery selector uses `id`, and the `id` is the same as the `name` (invalid HTML!),  use id to extract that value.

Putting it all together; use ([**See it in action at jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CB6w4/)) :

```
var maxPointsArray = $("span[id^=spnMX]").map (
    function (index) {
        var text    = $.trim (this.textContent);
        var idVal   = this.id.replace (/spnMX/, "");

        //-- This will make a two-dimensional array:
        return [ [idVal, text] ];
    }
).get ();

console.log (maxPointsArray.length);  
console.log (maxPointsArray);
```

For the sample spans, this code gives this result in the console:

```
4
[ ["45", "16"], ["46", "10"], ["47", "11"], ["48", "5"] ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanations.  I like the code and it was closest to what I'd started with.  I'm going to have to search out more details of what you were saying in the 2nd and 3rd bullet points.  BTW, those span's aren't my code, so I was just posting what what from the original site.  The rest of their code doesn't look much better.  :)  Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome; glad to help.  I know those spans weren't yours (I frequent the Greasemonkey tag), BUT invalid code gets changed/fixed more often, so if your script relies on the *valid* parts more, your code will fit the page longer (hopefully). :)

Comment: For more details, I updated the answer with [a link to a `.map()` reference](http://www.jqapi.com/#p=map).

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
atr = $(this).attr('name');
```

Answer (score 1):

> "There are two values that I need from each of these elements. I need
>   the number that comes after the "spnMX" and the text of the span."

`<span>` elements aren't allowed `name` attributes btw.

Seeing as your ID's are exactly the same as each name, you could use the following:

```
$("span[id^=spnMX]").each(function(){
  var text = this.innerHTML; 
    // Returns 16, 10, 11, 5. The text inside each <span>.
  var idNum = this.id.match(/[\d]+$/)[0]; 
    // Returns 45, 46, 47, 48. The parts of each ID after spnMX. 
});
```

Now you these variables, you should find the rest of your task fine :)

[**jsFiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/P4Eb6/1/)

Comment: Thank you.  I hadn't tried the .each functionality yet, but it's nice to see how it would be done.